# File Not found exception error in Inputstream Function

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am passing URL as string in FileInputstream function but it is giving me file not found exception error and when I run same URL on browser it is working fine.
Below I am mentioning my code.

```
 InputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("http://192.168.0.107:4911//CustomReports//report23.jrxml"));
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(input);
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
```

Kindly help me out
Thanks

Comment: If you don't have to compile the report, prefer using the `.jasper` file instead of the `.jrxml` file. This will make the reports execute faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `File(String)` constructor is not designed to be used with an URL but with a file from a file system.

You could use the `File(URI)` constructor to achieve your need.

Or more simply, you could create your URL with the `URL` class and invoke the `openStream()` method 
to open a connection to this URL and returns an `InputStream` for reading from that connection.

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://192.168.0.107:4911//CustomReports//report23.jrxml").openStream();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
InputStream input = new URL("http://192.168.0.107:4911//CustomReports//report23.jrxml").openStream();
```